# Using su with screen

Tags: linux, command-line, multiple-users

When I am under one of my user-names, I can fire off, say, `screen -S -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "say command"\015'`.  However, I cannot `su username screen -S -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "say command"\015'`; it complains that permission is denied.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The username that you'r using with su might not be a super user.

Just type like this,

```
su screen -S -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "say command"\015'
```

then type your password